# If statement in a switch block javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement, conditional-statements

Is it possible to use an if/else statement using the responses from the switch block, within the switch block in Javascript? Below is my attempt to do so. This is a CodeAcademy project where you must code your own adventure using switch blocks and conditional statements.

```
var user = prompt("You awake; dazed, blurred and lost. What do you do?").toLowerCase()
var day = 0;

switch (user) {
    case "look at the time":
        console.log("Good start, how long was I out for?");
        if (
        case "look at the time" && day === 0) {
            console.log("it's only been a few hours, but time is still ticking");
            day++
        } else if (day > 0) {
            console.log("it's been " + day + "s! Will I make it out of here");
            day++
        }
        break;
    case "figure out where I am":
        console.log("Yeah, how did I end up here in the first place?");
        if (
        case "figure out where I am" && day === 0) {
            console.log("This is a good checkpoint");
            day++
        }
        break;
    case 'run':
        console.log("Dry your eyes, find a direction, and hope for the best");
        break;
    case 'give up':
        console.log('Thanks for trying, have fun, where ever you are...');
        break;
    default:
        console.log("you fall back unconscious, hoping to wake again");
        day++;
        if (
        default) {
            return user;
        }
        if (
        case 'run' ||
        case 'give up') {
            console.log("It would have ended up coming down to this option anyway");
        }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to check (and can't) `case` again, just check for a `day`.

Comment: no, it's not possible to place if statements inside the `switch` block. You can only place `case`s there. And you cannot place `case`s inside `if`-conditions either. That's just a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work if you make a change to stop using the word `case` inside your `if` statement, for example it should look like this to perform a comparison to the `user` variable from the case statement:

```
if (user === "look at the time" && day === 0) {
    console.log("it's only been a few hours, but time is still ticking");
    day++
} else if (day > 0) {
    console.log("it's been " + day + "s! Will I make it out of here");
    day++
}
```

In this case the comparison `user === "look at the time"` is redundant because that logic is already being evaluated in the switch statement itself.  I just included it so you can see how to compare with the `user` variable, but it can be excluded entirely and have the same effect in this case.